# Get author and excerpt from URL

Tags: php

Trying to be tricky here, I want to show a list of articles with their author and excerpt. I'm using a custom field and want the user to just be able to list the URLs on their own line and that's it.

Is there a way to look up the non-rewritten url based on the friendly one? Then just pull the article ID from there via regex?

To further clarify:

Say this is the URL
http://www.site.com/2013/10/wearable-tech-trends-element14.html

Can I take it back (decode) to?
http://www.site.com/?p=123

So I can grab the 123 and use that to find the author and excerpt.

Comment: Maybe is my poor english, but I understand nothing. Can you post an example?

Comment: ok, example in the post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a function called [`url_to_postid`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/url_to_postid)

```
$id = url_to_postid( get_permalink(40) ); // $id will be 40
```

Actually (WP 3.6) it works only for standard posts and page, but with WP 3.7 it will also work for custom post types.

Comment: This is a good place to learn.. :) @AmalMurali